# Double notification when pinged on a followed post

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, follow-post

StackExchange recently implemented a feature that allows users to "follow" a post in the sense that they get notified on every edit/comment below that post, as if they were the post owners.

I find this to be very helpful, especially on meta, where one might want to follow discussions on answers, even if they are not actively mentioned in the comment.

But now I have a different problem. When I am pinged directly below a post that I follow, I get notified *twice*. This is definitely a bug, since it is not the case when someone pings me in a comment below one of my posts.

Comment: If someone wants to test, feel free to follow this post and leave a comment.

Comment: Yes, I too have experienced this. Definitely a minor bug,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [was fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345681/51) back in April/May.